# Can I execute a conditional inside of a plsql case statement then clause?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, plsql

I am building a script that replicates logic inside of a php script currently, and I've come to this section:

```
 switch ($_POST['type']) {
                    case 'person':
                        $type = '3';

                        if ($_POST['resident']) {

                            $type = '1';

                        }
```

I need to replicate this in my plsql script.

in my plsql script, I've currently got a case statement handling the setting of $type.

```
CASE v_type
    WHEN 'person'
        THEN v_application_type := '3';
```

I want to do something like

```
CASE v_type
    WHEN 'person'
        THEN v_application_type := '3';
        AND IF(v_resident = 'Y') THEN v_application_type :='1';
```

How can I nest a conditional inside of a switch like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
case v_type
    when 'person' then
        v_application_type := '3';

        if v_resident = 'Y' then
            v_application_type :='1';
        end if;
    else
        v_application_type := 'cheese';
end case;
```

Though it might be neater to bring that default `'3'` inside the `if` condition:

```
case v_type
    when 'person' then
        if v_resident = 'Y' then
            v_application_type := '1';
        else
            v_application_type := '3';
        end if;
    else
        v_application_type := 'cheese';
end case;
```

Or you could stick with `case`, as they do a similar job and switching styles midway might be confusing:

```
case v_type
    when 'person' then
        case v_resident
            when 'Y' then
                v_application_type := '1';
            else
                v_application_type := '3';
        end case;
    else
        v_application_type := 'cheese';
end case;
```

However if it's just to assign a value I would make the whole thing an expression:

```
v_application_type :=
    case v_type
        when 'person' then                
            case v_resident
                when 'Y' then '1'
                else '3'
            end
        else 'cheese'
    end;
```

(By the way, if `v_application_type` is a number, you wouldn't quote it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that if you remove the `AND` and add an `END IF`; which is clearer aligned differently:

```
CASE v_type
    WHEN 'person' THEN
        v_application_type := '3';
        IF v_resident = 'Y' THEN
            v_application_type :='1';
        END IF;
    ...
END CASE;
```

or change the case searching, which would involve repeating things but might be clearer:

```
CASE WHEN v_type = 'person' AND v_resident = 'Y' THEN
         v_application_type :='1';
     WHEN v_type = 'person' THEN
         v_application_type := '3';
     ...
END CASE;
```